# How to set status bar backgound color

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[image: SCREENSHOT]

above toolbar, the system time and everything is not visible, maybe it is color problem? please any solution?

Comment: What is your xml?

Comment: you should use the windowLightStatusBar to true, make the text white.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but Mike's answer seems like fulfilling my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In colors.xml you will see colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark. If I'm not mistaken you can change colorPrimaryDark to change it's color. You can also play around with colorAccent.

Update **

The above is for Pre Lollipop

This one is for Lollipop +

Add values-21/styles.xml in your project and add there android:statusBarColor

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: all my colors are shades of green color, not white at all, then why it is still not visible?

Comment: I have updated the answer, it depends on your android OS.

Comment: thank you so much, I edited my values-21/styles and added the `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>` and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

you can in your theme set the status color. for the text, it gives two styles, one white, the other is black.

> when android:windowLightStatusBar is set to true, status bar text color will be able to be seen when the status bar color is white, and vice-versa when android:windowLightStatusBar is set to false, status bar text color will be designed to be seen when the status bar color is dark.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        // this make the text white,or black
       <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        //this is the status bar background
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_theme</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: `statusBarColor` didn't work, however, `windowLightStatusBar` was working correctly, but clearly I didn't needed it. Anyways, thank you so much, Mikes answer worked.

Comment: @Abdullah, Ok, I give the `color_theme` which your custom color. then I think you want to set the status-bar background color not text